# How can I get the path of exported file (telerik RadGrid exporting)?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, export, radgrid

I'm exporting a PDF file using

```
RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ExportToPdf()
```

This is a sub. My question is: Can I get the exported file path somehow?

Thank you in advance,

Lajos Árpád.

Comment: Are you expecting to somehow be able to get the file path that the client chose to save the file to?

Comment: Either that (but I think that's impossible), or to store the pdf file on the server, but I don't know how can I set my grid to store the exported pdf on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you export, the NeedDataSource event will fire. Store the data into a simple ADO.NET Datatable.

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(double));
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            table.Rows.Add(i);

        (sender as RadGrid).DataSource = table;
    }
```

Self Explanatory. Removes the text boxes, leaves just the text.

```
public void ReplaceTextBoxes(Control ctrl)
{
    var q = new Stack<Control>(ctrl.Controls.OfType<Control>());
    while (q.Count > 0)
    {
        Control control = q.Pop();
        if (control is ITextControl)
        {
            ctrl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl((control as ITextControl).Text));
            ctrl.Controls.Remove(control);
        }
        if (control.HasControls())
            ReplaceTextBoxes(control);
    }
}
```

To store on the server, add an OnGridExporting event.

```
protected void RadGrid1_GridExporting(object sender, GridExportingArgs e)
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "RadGrid.pdf"))
    {
        byte[] output = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(e.ExportOutput);
        fs.Write(output, 0, output.Length);
    }

    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
}
```

You can change "RadGrid.pdf" to whatever you want it to be called.

And finally a button to make all this happen (or you can just call the ExportToPdf function wherever.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items)
        ReplaceTextBoxes(item);
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ExportToPdf();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying it out.

Comment: It creates the PDF, but the PDF is empty.

Comment: hold on ill update it, I was assuming you already had the rest of the code

Comment: Thank you for the update, I've already upvoted you because your desire to help. I have a NeedDatasource event and I successfully exported data to PDF for the client side. But it doesn't work on the server side, that's the main issue. I also have a GridExporting event, but it doesn't fire when I want to export to the server. It fires when I want to export to the client. I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: At last I've finished, I still have problems in opening a RadWindow with RegisterStartupScript after the file is successfully exported on the server side, but that's a different issue. Thank you for your help.